# Send keystroke to notepad with ahk library

Tags: python, python-3.x, autohotkey

I got this code for, open notepad and write '1321' on it, now that's the code:

```
from ahk import AHK

ahk = AHK(executable_path="C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe")

ahk.run_script('Run Notepad')
win = ahk.find_window(title=b'Untitled - Notepad')
win.send('1321')
```

The script run, open the notepad and then, i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/GAMING/PycharmProjects/Snek/Snek.py", line 7, in <module>
win.send('1321')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

How can i fix?

Comment: it can means that it didn't find window - so `win` is `None` - and then it can't do `None.send("1321")`

Comment: Thanks, i fix it now, with right name win = ahk.find_window(title=b'Untitled - Notepad of Windows')

Comment: is this working?

Comment: Yeah, is working